# IlligalStateException in ListView (no async task or other non-UI thread involved)

Tags: android, listview

An (android) application has a global shopping cart. Various UI components can affect the cart, for example adding/removing items from it, all within the UI thread. Whenever the cart-state changes, it emits an event onto a "hub" which broadcasts it to all subscribed Handlers. The handlers, for example, update the Total label or refresh the listview (notifyDataSetChanged).

Under a "stress test" where the user is scrolling through the cart while removing items from it by clicking on them -- I sometimes get the IlligalStateException. Nowhere is the model updated asynchronously.

The app guarantees eventual consistency between the model (cart) and the ListView, just that the propagation of the cart change event involves going through a layer of handlers/queues, so the UI may be temporarily out of sync with the model, until the queued event is processed.

I can think of few possible ways to address this (none tested yet), but none feel particularly attractive:

1. The listview-adapter might return a dummy (filler) item for out-of-bounds position, expecting a model-update event will "fix" this state.
2. Posting the cart-changed event at the front of the handlers queues -- discouraged by the Android SDK doc. The rationale is that I suspect the Listview is redrawn (on scroll) before the enqueued "notifyDataSetChanged" is popped from the queue and processed.
3. The adapter caches the global cart state, acting like a
   double-buffer. Thus, the Listvew renders of off the adapter's cache,
   not the global cart. Feels like a burden though ;)

Any better suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of implementing copy on write mechanism..Whenever you have to write data make a copy of the the listview data items,modify it and then give the modified list to the listview for rendering..There might be performance hit, you will have to calculate whether it is acceptable...